# Is it a good idea to contain everything in one try-catch

Tags: java, try-catch

I am using java, and all exceptions in my codes are derived from java.lang.exception. Is it a good idea to contain everything in one try-catch? Is it a good idea to add try-catch for every difficult function?

Because I want to let my codes run better in a lazy way, which means no exceptions will cause my program crash, e.g., catch IndexOutOfBoundsException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException,SQLGrammarException ......

following are my codes:

```
public MyResult function1(){
    MyResult myResult = new MyResult();
    try{
        //all codes here
    }catch(Exception e){
        LOGGER.error(e);
        myResult.setException(e);
    }finally{
        return myResult;
    }
}

//more same functions using same try-catch here

public MyResult functionN(){
    MyResult myResult = new MyResult();
    try{
        //all codes here
    }catch(Exception e){
        LOGGER.error(e);
        myResult.setException(e);
    }finally{
        return myResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Impossible to say.  Generally you use a `catch` when you have some meaningful way of responding to an exception, and you use a `finally` when you have some logic that needs to happen regardless of the result of the `try/catch`.  How to handle your exceptions or what logic you want to perform is entirely up to you.  There is no one universal design for all software.

Comment: What is the difference ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> all exceptions in my codes are derived from `java.lang.Exception`

This may not be a good idea, because there is a class of exceptions that needs to be defined from `java.lang.RuntimeException` - namely, exceptions that indicate programming errors, i.e. situations that require changing the program in order to be fixed.

> Is it a good idea to contain everything in one try-catch?

No, it is not. You should add `try`/`catch` as needed, placing them around the blocks of code that may throw them, and only in situations where your code is prepared to handle the exception in some meaningful way.

> Is it a good idea to add try-catch for every difficult function?

You should not place `try`/`catch` inside methods that do not know how to handle the exception. A better approach is to let the exception go up the invocation chain until it hits the method that is prepared to handle the exception.

There are situations when such method would be at the very top of the invocation chain, in which case the method often logs and exits or returns an error status.

Comment: One of the only times it is acceptable to use a catch-all block is for logging, but even then, that should log and then throw the exception up. EDIT - @dasblinkenlight you must type faster than me...

Answer (score 3):

So. Basically you should place your `try`/`catch` only around the parts of the code that could throw exceptions. This will keep your code better structured and will improve the readability.

Personally, I am not a big fan of using `(Exception e)`. If somebody else reads your code he won't know which exceptions might occur. I think using only the exceptions that might be thrown in the `catch` blocks is better.